# Kafka Connect Jdbc Source Data Schema

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Does the connector generate a generic Schema such as **record** with the map of column->value in it, or each table get its own schema that would map to a different class through binding. That is in the first scenario, trough binding all record across all table would bind to a record class, that contain a map.

I implemented some similar functionality in the past, and what I did was creating a generic record class containing a map with the field and value, which is consistent with what the underlying JDBC API returns.

Although this seems to defy the purpose of schema, hence I wonder how it works. How can I investigate this?

Comment: Each table gets its own schema... `ResultSet` becomes a schema https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/source/SchemaMapping.java#L49-L80

Comment: Thank you for the hint ? How does that related to generic avro ?

Comment: Connect framework has its own `Schema` object. The `AvroConverter` can interpret this, and create an avro `Schema` class

Comment: Can you share links as to where can find documentation around that ? A doc about Connect own schema object ?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Schema.html and https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/Converter.html

Comment: So far i am about to check the following link https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/master/connect-streams-pipeline#example-3b-jdbc-source-connector-with-genericavro---keystringnull-and-valuegenericavro. Had it in the background for a while and that's why i mention genericAvro. This is by confluent folks. I have a hard time reconciling what is in there and what you mention here. but i guess i need digging.

Comment: I think I understand now what you meant. Sorry :) and thank you

Comment: In the Connector properties, you would have `value.converter`, which is an implementation of `Converter` interface I linked. `AvroConverter` doesn't use SpecificRecords to my knowledge, as they are dynamically built records. `JsonConverter` would also work, only the messages would be larger in terms of final byte sizes